# Having issues access my git function through visual code IDE

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

thanks for taking the time

Im currently working on a project that requires me to generate jupyter notebooks, however i am unable to run the build function through my terminal. The image below is the error i am recieving.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW3EB.png)

I was expecting it to run as ussual, installing other libraries didnt have any issues

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)